# How do I perform Inverse Laplace on this function?

Tags: inverse, laplace-transform

$$
F(S) = \frac{-S+11}{S^2-2S-3}
$$

Howo do I find $f(t)$? What is a good strategy for attacking these types of problems? Thanks a bunch in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Factor the denominator:

$$s^2-2 s-3 = (s-3)(s+1)$$

Then note that

$$\frac{-s+11}{(s-3)(s+1)} = \frac{A}{s-3}+ \frac{B}{s+1}$$

where

$$A+B=-1 \quad \text{and} \quad A-3 B=11$$

so that $A=2$ and $B=-3$.  Thus

$$F(s) = \frac{2}{s-3}-\frac{3}{s+1}$$

Now know that the inverse Laplace transform of $1/(s+a)$ is $e^{-a t}$ when $s \gt -a$.  You should be able to see this from

$$\int_0^{\infty} dt \, e^{-a t} \, e^{-s t} = \frac{1}{s+a}$$

You should be able to take it from here.

Alternatively, you can use the residue theorem if you know some complex analysis.  Here, you see that the poles of $F$ are at $s=-1$ and $s=3$.  The ILT is the sum of the residues of $F(s) e^{s t}$ at the poles:

$$\operatorname*{Res}_{s=-1} \frac{-s+11}{(s-3)(s+1)} e^{s t} = \frac{12}{-4} e^{-t}$$
$$\operatorname*{Res}_{s=3} \frac{-s+11}{(s-3)(s+1)} = \frac{8}{4} e^{3 t}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for this very informative answer. Because I'm terrible at math I had to google how to factor 2nd degree polynomials. I found this guide helpful: [link](http://m.se.hccs.edu/Users/douglas.bump/MyDocuments/handouts/NoFuss.pdf). Wish I could give upvotes to the answers to my question, but I guess I need some more reputation first :)

Answer (score 1):

Related problem: [(I)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493272/laplace-transformation-problem/493296#493296). Use partial fraction to get

> $$ -\frac{3}{\left( s+1 \right)}+\frac{2}{\left( s-3 \right)}. $$

Now, I think you can finish it. For alternative approach see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248330/inverse-laplace-transform-of-fraction-fs-large-frac2s1s29).

**Note:**

> $$ \mathcal{L}\{e^{ax}\}(s) = \frac{1}{s-a}. $$

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:** Let $F:S\mapsto\frac{-S+11}{S^2-2S-3}$

A well known integral:

- $\int\limits_0^\infty\mathrm e^{-St}\mathrm e^{at}\mathrm dt=\frac1{S-a}$ (can you prove this?).

A well known Laplace transform:

- Let $e_a:t\mapsto\mathrm e^{at}$, then $(Le_a)(S)=\frac1{S-a}$ for every $S\gt a$ (can you prove this?).

A decomposition:

- $S^2-2S-3=(S-3)(S+1)$ (do you know why?) hence $F(S)=\frac{u}{S-3}+\frac{v}{S+1}$ for some real numbers $u$ and $v$ (can you compute them?).

A consequence:

- $F=uL(e_3)+vL(e_{-1})$ (can you prove this?), thus $F=L(ue_3+ve_{-1})$ (can you deduce this?).

Note finally that $F$ is a Laplace transform on the domain $(3,+\infty)$ only.